# Presto Cassandra Connector

Tags: cassandra, presto

I am working on Cassandra, We are using Cassandra community edition. We are having Scenario where we need to join two tables. Datastax will support joining two tables in Cassandra. As I said we are using community edition we can go for this.

I am looking into presto connector, I want to understand Presto will support joining two tables in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet supported in Presto. However there is an initiative to push down joins to Presto connectors, see: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/18.